# Virtual functions and templates in C++ - can they be replaced with other (existing in C++) operations?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual-functions

For example concept of Templates in C++ are for comfort as compiler generates some additional code, for your class or for your function, isn't it? So we could live without template by  doing some additional (manual work).

What about virtual functions???

Are there any situations where both of them are irreplaceable?

Comment: What do you mean by "for comfort?"

Comment: When you get right down to it, the only thing that's irreplaceable is the raw processor instructions. So, in some sense, everything above that (assembly opcodes and every programming language) is "for comfort", and we could live without it. So I don't see what meaning this question has; with programming you always get to choose your preferred level of abstraction. For a less drastic example, you could live without addition in C++ if you implemented your own addition algorithm using bitwise operations.

Comment: I mean if it adds new features to C++ programing language that we can't get by using the all remaining operations and features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can live without templates by doing more manual work (write the code that the compiler writes, or use `void*` to remove type specifics).

Yes, we can live without polymorphism by doing more manual work (using switch statements, or storing your own vtable struct).

> Are there instances where they're irreplaceable?

The template and polymorphism approaches give you type safety and compiler enforced behavior (e.g. pure virtual) that can't be replaced with some of the manual methods.  For example, `std::sort` is safer to use than `qsort` which operates on `void*`.  These manual methods can result in lots of code that has to be bug free and maintained.  So it depends on your definition of "irreplaceable".  With or without these features, these languages are still [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).  Theoretically, you can compute anything in a Turing complete language, so we could theoretically replace all languages with BrainF*ck...  We just choose not to ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite the same.

Templates effectively generate functions with various signatures at compile time. You could pretty easily copy-paste or code generate all the equivalent methods yourself.

Virtual methods are used to make decisions at runtime, so while they do make programmers' work easier, they rather more difficult to replace. You can't just copy-paste code to simulate virtual functions, but instead you would have to implement almost the same thing yourself, using either a vtable-like table of function pointers or some other alternate approach.

In short virtual functions make it much easier to do some things that would be difficult otherwise, but it's a different set of things than templates affect.

Answer (score 1):

Of course; before polymorphism was available, and even now in the code of people who do not understand polymorphism, the Giant Switch Statement takes its place.

Comment: The giant switch statement does not allow users of your library to add cases to it. You need a bit more work to fully emulate polymorphism without virtual functions (like implementing your own vtable).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is possible to use polymorphism to achieve the same ends as with templates.  However, it does as you suspect take more work.  There are other trade offs to consider including performance and maintainability.  Those come into play when I make the decision which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you could do everything you would need to do with AND and NOT operations.  Everything else is gravy.